# How to collapse a multi-dimensional array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

**Background:**

Hey all, I am experimenting with external APIs and am trying to pull in all of the followers of a User from a site and apply some sorting.

I have refactored a lot of the code, HOWEVER, there is one part that is giving me a really tough time. I am convinced there is an easier way to implement this than what I have included and would be really grateful on any tips to do this in a much more eloquent way.

My goal is simple. I want to collapse an array of arrays of hashes (I hope that is the correct way to explain it) into one array of hashes.

**Problem Description:**

I have an array named `f_collections`which has 5 elements. Each element is an array of size 200. Each sub-element of these arrays is a hash of about 10 key-value pairs. My best representation of this is as follows:

```
f_collections = [ collection1, collection2, ..., collection5 ]
collection1 = [ hash1, hash2, ..., hash200]
hash1 = { user_id: 1, user_name: "bob", ...}
```

I am trying to collapse this multi-dimensional array into one array of hashes. Since there are five collection arrays, this means the results array would have 1000 elements - all of which would be hashes.

```
followers = [hash1, hash2, ..., hash1000]
```

**Code (i.e. my attempt which I do not want to keep):**

I have gotten this to work with a **very ugly** piece of code (see below), with nested if statements, blocks, for loops, etc... This thing is a nightmare to read and I have tried my hardest to research ways to do this in a simpler way, I just cannot figure out how. I have tried flatten but it doesn't seem to work.

I am mostly just including this code to show I have tried very hard to solve this problem, and while yes I solved it, there must be a better way!

Note: I have simplified some variables to integers in the code below to make it more readable.

```
for n in 1..5 do
        if n < 5
          (0..199).each do |j|
            if n == 1
              nj = j
            else
              nj = (n - 1) * 200 + j
            end

            @followers[nj] = @f_collections[n-1].collection[j]
          end
        else
          (0..199).each do |jj|
            njj = (4) * 200  + jj
            @followers[njj] = @f_collections[n-1].collection[jj]
          end
        end

      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh... so It is not an array objects that hold collections of hashes. Kind of. Lets give it another try:

```
flat = f_collection.map do |col|
  col.collection
end.flatten
```

which can be shortened (and is more performant) to:

```
flat = f_collection.flat_map do |col|
  col.collection
end
```

This works because the items in the `f_collection` array are objects that have a `collection` attribute, which in turn is an array.

So it is "array of things that have an array that contains hashes"

---

Old Answer follows below. I leave it here for documentation purpose. It was based on the assumption that the data structure is an array of array of hashes.

Just use `#flatten` (or `#flatten!` if you want this to be "inline")

```
flat = f_collections.flatten
```

Example

```
sub1 = [{a: 1}, {a: 2}]
sub2 = [{a: 3}, {a: 4}]
collection = [sub1, sub2]

flat = collection.flatten # returns a new collection
puts flat #> [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>3}, {:a=>4}]

# or use the "inplace"/"destructive" version 
collection.flatten! # modifies existing collection
puts collection #> [{:a=>1}, {:a=>2}, {:a=>3}, {:a=>4}]
```

Some recommendations for your existing code:

Do not use `for n in 1..5`, use Ruby-Style enumeration:

```
["some", "values"].each do |value|
  puts value
end
```

Like this you do not need to hardcode the length (`5`) of the array (did not realize you removed the variables that specify these magic numbers). If you you want to detect the last iteration you can use `each_with_index`:

```
a = ["some", "home", "rome"]
a.each_with_index do |value, index|
  if index == a.length - 1
    puts "Last value is #{value}"
  else
    puts "Values before last: #{value}"
  end
end
```

While `#flatten` will solve your problem you might want to see how DIY-solution could look like:

```
def flatten_recursive(collection, target = [])
  collection.each do |item|
    if item.is_a?(Array)
      flatten_recursive(item, target)
    else
      target << item
    end
  end
  target
end
```

Or an iterative solution (that is limited to two levels):

```
def flatten_iterative(collection)
  target = []
  collection.each do |sub|
    sub.each do |item|
      target << item
    end
  end
  target
end
```

Comment: Hey pascal! Thanks for your answer.

I just tried this again:
followers = f_collections.flatten
And afterwards when I check the size it still says 5. When I check the value of followers[1], it is still a collection of 200 hashes, not a single hash.

In your example you only show one hash key/value pair, but in each hash there are about 10. Does that change anything? For example:

sub1 = [{a: 1, b: 3, c:6, ...}, {a: 2}]
sub2 = [{a: 3}, {a: 4}]
collection = [sub1, sub2]

Comment: Also - I removed the variable name to make the example simpler, but I was not aware of this each_with_index function! Awesome tip!

Comment: Hello @gallant
No, the number of keys in the hash or the number of elements in the arrays does not make a difference.
Can you provide a simplified set of data so i can run my code against it?

Are you sure you checked on the new collection that is returned by "flatten"?

Comment: I updated the sample to show the differences between "flatten" and "flatten!"

Comment: Hey Pascal. Yeah I am familiar with the "!" operator for in-line, but the way I wrote it should work. The problem is when I do mock-ups of the data it never represents it well. Here is an example of the data from one of the collections:
https://pastebin.com/Gxa344F0

(I hope that works!) It seems to be within a "hashie" wrapper.

Comment: Ps. I am just on my way home but I will be back in about 1 hour. Really appreciate your help on this one Pascal and just wanted to let you know I am not ignoring you if I don't respond quickly :)

Comment: Hello @gallant

If your datastructure is indeed an "array of array of hashes" then "flatten" should work.
Perhaps you can provide a simple example set of data, that has the same structure?

Comment: Hi Pascal - unfortunately I am not sure how to mock up this data as I get it from an external API request.

I called it an array of array of hashes because I can access a hash by using the following command:
f_collections[0].collection[0]

This would give me the first user in the first collection. If I `puts` this, it shows me the entire hash with all the user data.

For instance I can query the hash like this:
`f_collections[0].collection[0].user_name`
and it gives me the user name. Would that not imply an array of arrays of hashes??

Comment: One more thing - if you have any ideas how I could give you a sample of this data I am all ears, I just am not sure how I would export the data to a format that would be useful

Comment: Hi Pascal!
Yes! It worked, oh man thank you so much for this. I will mark it answered.

Can I ask - what did you mean by "so It is not an array objects that hold collections of hashes."? 

I will do some research into this flat_map method, but interested if you could give any information on what lead you to that approach. Thank you so much